# Getting error while reading excel file in R

Tags: r

I would like to use `XLConnect` to write some data on `XLSX` file. 
but this exception occured:

> Error: NoSuchMethodException (Java): No constructor matching the given
>   parameters

Comment: `rJava` is devil. Try `readxl` package.

Comment: No example so testing not possible. Need code and data.